# Prove that every problem in P is reducible

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [For two problems A and B, if A is in P, then A is reducible to B?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208848/for-two-problems-a-and-b-if-a-is-in-p-then-a-is-reducible-to-b)

Given two problems $A$ and $B$, if $A$ is in $\def\P{{\mathcal P}}\P$ then $A$ is reducible to $B$. ($A < B$)

Why does it not matter if $B$ is in $\P$ or $\mathcal{NP}$?
Why can just knowing that $A$ is in $\P$ mean that it is reducible regardless of $B$?

Comment: Please state your definition of reducible.  In these questions it is vital that you know what the terms mean with great precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've sort of answered your own question.

"$A$ is reducible to $B$" means "Given a black box that solves problem $B$ in constant time, we can solve problem $A$ in polynomial time."  Since $A$ is in $P$, this statement is always true: we can simply throw away our black box to $B$ and solve $A$ without it.

Comment: Thanks, rewriting it like that clears up some of my confusion.

Comment: I have a question regarding this answer: Why does B have to be solved in constant time?